# Jquery Switch Case Condition not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I have some jquery to change my full page background when they reach some div, but unfortunately there's something wrong with switch case statement

this is the first code (ascending)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();
        var slide1 = $('#slide1').offset().top;
        var slide2 = $('#slide2').offset().top;

        switch(true){
        case top >= slide1:
            menu.removeClass('bg-full').addClass('bg-full2');
            break;
        case top >= slide2:
            menu.removeClass('bg-full2').addClass('bg-full3');
            break;
        default:
        menu.removeClass('bg-full2').addClass('bg-full');}
```

code above is working with bg-full (*default statement*) / bgfull2 (*1st case*) **but the (*2nd case*) is ignored**

and I m trying second code (descending)

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    var slide1 = $('#slide1').offset().top;
    var slide2 = $('#slide2').offset().top;

    switch(true){
    case top >= slide2:
        menu.removeClass('bg-full2').addClass('bg-full3');
        break;
    case top >= slide1:
        menu.removeClass('bg-full').addClass('bg-full2');
        break;
    default:
    menu.removeClass('bg-full2').addClass('bg-full');
    }
```

code above is working with bg-full2 (*3rd case*) / bgfull3 (*2nd case*) **but the (*default statement*) is ignored when I'm reached the 3rd case**

please helpme thanks,
sorry my bad english

Comment: Why is your swtich expression true?

Comment: If it does not reach the default case, this means it matched a prior case with a break statement. When you add console.log(caseNum) to each case, what is the console output? (The issue of using a switch here is strange, as others have pointed out, but it is not the source of your problem).

Comment: @awrak I dont have many knowledges on jquery, I just follow the pattern,  And i see this pattern on stackoverflow, so far this syntax/pattern is work,

Comment: It is syntactically valid. But it's strange because a switch statement is intended for situations where the switch expression is a variable, not a constant -- what you have done is reinvented if () {} else if () {} else {}

Comment: @semicolon after reached to 3rd case, its break all case (2nd, and default). i forgot to add this to the question

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't make sense of that. How have you confirmed that the first two cases did not evaluate to true? It is, as far as I can see, the only way your default case will not be reached, so I suspect top is actually always greater than or equal to slide1 and slide2.

Comment: My god, I think I get it. You are expecting it to evaluate EVERY true case PLUS default! Is that what you mean? Because the break statements cause you to leave the switch block. Remove them, and every true statement plus default will match. However I should advise that now even more than before, switch is the inappropriate way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this,

```
 $(window).scroll(function () {
    var top = $(this).scrollTop();
    var slide1 = $('#slide1').offset().top;
    var slide2 = $('#slide2').offset().top;

    if (top > slide2 || top === slide2)
    {
        menu.removeClass('bg-full2').addClass('bg-full3');
        return;
    }

    if (top > slide1 || top === slide1)
    {
        menu.removeClass('bg-full').addClass('bg-full2');
        return;
    }

    menu.removeClass('bg-full2').addClass('bg-full');
  }
```

Comment: np, though I just deleted the comment since it no longer made sense :) Sometimes the most mysterious questions are the ones where you have to get inside someone's head...

Comment: bro, I try this but it's not working, even dreamweaver highlight break; as invalid syntax for if / else condition.

Comment: user67036, you're correct, the example above is not valid as written. I didn't notice earlier since the premise is correct. Most likely user8\d+ introduced those break statements accidentally when cutting and pasting. Just remove them.

Comment: Hey user86745458, your edits didn't address the problem. You don't have a breakable block there -- `if` statements are not breakable themselves; one can only use a break statement in a switch or loop block (and its child blocks, irrespective of statement type). I'm also a bit unsure what the change you made to the condition expressions was meant to achieve.

Comment: I see you've updated again ... unfortunately, `continue` is a statement exclusive to loop statements -- for, for-in, for-of, while, and do-while. It's for jumping back to the top of a loop, and its use here would throw an error. There are no special control flow statements to be used in the body of an if block: the block's statements are either executed or they are not. The solution was not to change `break` to `continue`, but to remove those lines.